# Managing vertical scrolling in a UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, scroll, rich-text-editor

I try to get a content editable `UIWebView` with a "normal" scrolling operation, so that when the text cursor is going to be hidden by the keyboard, the `UIWebView` scrolls to prevent that. I read the "Managing the Keyboard" document from [iOS developer library](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html) and got no result, using the scrollView property of my `UIWebView`. I also found numerous tricks on the web, using ScrollView properties/methods or javascript commands but cannot obtain a normal scrolling operation, like any `NSTextView` does on MacOS for example. Do you know any solution to this problem?

[**EDITED**] Got the solution, and created a method fired by a `NSTimer`. To get the caret Y position, one should get the selection of the active element, and insert a dummy node. Then getting the node.offsetTop property gives the caretY. Do not forget the remove the node...

Comment: Hi Denis, could you please give a more detailed solution of what you have done? I am also facing trouble with UIWebView, content editable and erratic scrolling behavior.

Comment: FYI: you can fill in the answer yourself and accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the way Apple does it in their examples (I no longer remember what project name that was):

1.You register for keyboard notifications(the keyboard send a notification every time it shows up or it gets hidden):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

2.Get the keyboard's size (you are interested in the height) and scroll if that point is not contained in the view:

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{

NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    // If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;

CGPoint point;

point = CGPointMake(0, activeTextField.frame.origin.y + activeTextField.frame.size.height);

if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, point ))
{
    CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, activeTextField.frame.origin.y+activeTextField.frame.size.height-kbSize.height);
    [scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
}
```

Don't forget do reverse things when hiding keyboard and remove the observers if you push to another view controller.
This example is used with text fields on a UIScrollView but I'm sure you can easily adapt it.

Personally if I also manage the web side, I prefer to create the webpages 320px wide, set my webView sizeToFit, add it on top of a UIScrollView and manage the scrolling from there. For textFields, I simply get the container for the selected textField using javascript and get it's coordinates.